# Can the 90th percentiles of two sub populations both be lower than the overall?

Tags: quantiles

Consider two populations, $A$ and $B$. $A + B = C$. Meaning $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive of $C$.

Given the above if I calculate the 90th percentile of some metric for all populations is it possible that

$P90_C \ge P90_A$ and
$P90_C \ge P90_B$

I'm not good at combining P90s in my head and can't mathematically prove it.

Comment: What do you mean by "mutually exclusive"? That the values that appear in $A$ are all different from the values that appear in $B$? Or something else?

Comment: Taking an example of income. If I had a population of people C where each person has an income. Groups A and B are "mutually exclusive" if any person in A is NOT in B (and vice versa). But income values could exists in both sets (i.e. a person in group A makes 50K and a different person in group B also makes 50K)

Comment: You're using "$+$" to indicate a union of disjoint (multi)sets here? Then yes, that can happen.

Comment: *"Meaning $A$ and $B$ are partitions of $C$."* This is the same as what you wrote (as long as both $A$, $B$ are non-empty).

Comment: Yes, and it is not difficult to arrange that. See my paper from 2003:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-006-0050-7

Comment: Can you make that more clear?

Are you suggesting it matters that you're considering the 90th percentiles or two populations, as opposed to any others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's possible

```
set.seed(0)
N = 1000
i = 0
max_iter = 100
while (i < max_iter) {
  i = i + 1
  p = runif(1)
  g = runif(N) < p
  x = rnorm(N)
  q = quantile(x, 0.90) # group C
  q1 = quantile(x[g], 0.90) # group A
  q2 = quantile(x[!g], 0.90) # group B
  if ((q > q1) && (q > q2)) {
    print(sprintf("i:%i, q:%.4f, q1:%.4f, q2:%.4f", i, q, q1, q2))
    break
  }
}
```

result is

```
i:11, q:1.2368, q1:1.2351, q2:1.2360
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this is only due to the values being *averaged*, because the N does not work out such that there is any population member at exactly the 90th percentile. This can't happen with exact quantiles - if you set the subgroup and full population sizes to something evenly divisible by the quantile (say 500/500/1000), you'll never find that both subpopulations' 90th quantiles are higher than the full population's.

Answer (score 16):

This is possible when we consider computations of quantiles that are not exact.

Example

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5)
B = c(1,2,3,4,5)
C = c(x,y)
quantile(A,0.9) # this computes as 4.6        
quantile(B,0.9) # this computes as 4.6        
quantile(C,0.9) # this computes as 5
```

It if we have instead the condition that the populations A and B are with $10k_A +1$ and $10k_B +1$ members* then the 90-th percentile should be equal to or in-between the 90-th percentiles of A and B.

---

*in this case the 90-th percentiles are exactly the (9k+1)-th order statistics.

Answer (score 6):

It is certainly possible.

As an example, consider finite populations or two finite samples.
Let $x^A_{(0.9n)}$ be the 90th percentile of sample $A$ that has $n$ members, and $x^B_{(0.9m)}$ be the 90th percentile of sample $B$ that has $m$ members.

Suppose now that it holds
$${\rm condition\;1:}\quad  x^A_{(0.9n)} < x^B_{(0.9m)}.$$

Suppose also that the following holds

$${\rm condition\; 2:}\quad \forall\, x^A: x^A > x^A_{(0.9n)} \implies x^A > x^B_{(0.9m)}.$$

Namely, it so happens that all members of $A$ with value higher than its 90th percentile, are also higher in value than the 90th percentile of sample $B$.

If we pool the two samples creating $C$, there will be $0.1\times (n+m)$ elements higher than $x^B_{(0.9m)}$ in $C$.

Hence we will get
$$x^A_{(0.9n)} < x^B_{(0.9m)} = x^C_{(0.9(n+m))}.$$

Comment: I don't follow the final bit of notation, what does it mean to find the 90th percentile of sample B with n+m members? Subpopulation B doesn't have n+m members. I also don't see any expression showing that Subpopulation B's 90th percentile is smaller than the full population's. I don't think the condition that A's >90th percentile members be uniformly higher than B's is sufficient - if A = {0,0,0,10,10,10,10) and B={0,0,0,1,1,1,1), all of A's >50th percentile is higher than B's >50th percentile, and A's 50th percentile is greater than the full population's, but B's is 50th percentile is not.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie apologies, that was just a typo. Corrected.

Comment: But this still doesn't show that both A's and B's Nth percentile can be lower than C's. It seems to show that if one's is, the other's isn't. The final line states that B's 90th percentile *is not less* than C's 90th percentile.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Your numerical example does not obey the conditions explicitly stated in my post. In your example the 90th percentile of $B$ is not higher than the 90th percentile of $A$, but it should be, to match my reasoning.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The OP asked about weak inequality.

Comment: Ah, you are using the equality. I missed that and interpreted the question as the stronger statement $$P90_C > P90_A \qquad \text{and} \qquad
P90_C > P90_B$$ instead of $$P90_C \ge P90_A \qquad \text{and} \qquad
P90_C \ge P90_B$$ That makes it even  possible for infinite populations. For $P90_B \geq P90_A$ we have  $$P90_A \leq  P90_C \leq P90_B$$ and if also $P90_B  = P90_A$ then $$P90_A = P90_C = P90_B$$ The finite populations make it extra interesting because we  do not need neccesarily $P90_B = P90_A$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Indeed. Moreover, my post implicitly assumes that the 90th percentile value exists in the realized values, that's why is confined to produce just an equality. Your example in your post, where the 90th percentile is in-bewteen realized values due to the cardinality of the A and B samples, leads to the C 90th percentile being strictly higher.